# Does my routers self-signed certificate ever change?

Tags: tls, router

I have no idea how this works but if I install my routers self-signed certificate for log-in through HTTPS (ex : https:// 192.168.1.1) and then reset the router to factory default, will the certificate I installed previously still be valid?

Comment: Guess so. Why? Does your browser report it as changed?

Comment: If you are adding the self-signed certificate by yourself and it is not supplied with the equipment, the certificate will definitely be gone after factory-reset. But I don't see the problem, if you can do it once, you can also again upload "self-sign" certificate after factory reset.

Comment: I noticed that logging in through the IP address and then the quick setup URL posted in the manual offered completely separate certificates and I was just curious. I will be testing when nobody is using the network.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your router. The certificate might be pre-generated in the factory in which case it will not change with a factory reset. But more likely is that the certificate will be generated on first startup in which case it will change after a factory reset. There is also the possibility that the factory reset is not a full reset and will preserve settings like the certificate. Or given the grasp on security several vendors have it might also be that the certificate is generated not based on real random data but on the MAC address of the device or similar constant data.

Comment: That's how it *should* be. But does regeneration actually happen for any routers? Can you name one?

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff: I don't have personal experiences with much devices and I don't usually factory reset. Also not all devices support https. But there is interesting related research in this area, see [Widespread Weak Keys in Network Devices](https://factorable.net/).